# native dependencies in gradle

Tags: java, c++, gradle, native

I want to build a java project with several dependencies in gradle, some are jar dependencies from the maven central repository, some are other java project dependencies, but there is also a native JNI dependency. I've managed to build the native dependency with gradle as a seperate project.

Now I want to import the compiled .so library as a depedency in my java project. I thought it would work something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':nameofnativedependency')
}
```

The project is also listed in my settings.gradle file. However, when I compile the project, I can get an error:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':test
>
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.

So something must be misconfigured. What is the right way (I hope there is one) to compile a native project and import the .so file in the calling project?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://discuss.gradle.org/t/native-dependencies-in-gradle/10689

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle native plugin uses the new [rule based software model](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/software_model.html). Model elements are not instantiated until after build.gradle has veen processed, and once instantiated they are immutable. To access those elements, you need to put your code inside the `components` closure, and access model elements through the `$` variable (bearing in mind that elements accessed that way will be instantiated, therefore immutable).

To integrate a java build with a native build, you will probably want to use the [java software model](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_software.html) plugins, instead of the legacy java plugin. I have been playing around with it, and have a [buildscript](https://github.com/bgorven/Hello/blob/master/build.gradle) that I'm starting to feel a little proud of, incorporating all of the steps from generating headers from class files, building libs, copying into src/main/resources to be bundled in the jar, then extracting and loading libs at runtime (though this part's not quite done yet; [Scijava's native library loader](https://github.com/scijava/native-lib-loader) is probably the way to go).